# compute following integral with respect to Hausdorff measure

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, hausdorff-measure

I would like to compute the following integral
$$
\int_{x^2 + y^2 = r^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} d\mathcal{H}(x, y)
$$

## My Attempt

I tried the following
$$
\begin{align}
    \int_{x^2 + y^2 = r^2} \frac{1}{r} d\mathcal{H}(x, y) = \frac{1}{r}\mathcal{H}(\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\, :\, x^2 + y^2 = r^2\}) = \frac{1}{r} \cdot 2 \pi r = 2 \pi
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Does Hausdoff equal Lebesgue measure here?  Otherwise be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple curves the Hausdorff measure $\mathcal{H}^1$ is just $\mathcal{L}^1$ the 1d Lebesgue measure. Your result is correct.

Comment: You have to be a bit careful when you talk about Lebesgue measure on a curve rather than a subset of the line.

Comment: In fact, the push-forward of Lebesgue measure under a natural parametrization, but here it's a circle with measure $R d\theta$...